"Imshow" not showing in top of "scatter"
I am willing to plot two different things in one image. I want to see the evolution of some probabilities in time, together with a cone which limits their expansion. I plot the first one using scatter, because it's a set of probabilities for each moment in time. I plot the second one using imshow, but it appears in the background, behind markers from the scatter. I then get some white columns in the cone which I would like to remove.
I have tried setting alpha=0 for some specific values (the ones with zero probability, these are the ones that overlap the cone), but did not succeed. I leave my code here so that you can have a look at it.
https://github.com/mikelpuy/Imshow-and-scatter
Thanks beforehand.

To maximise your chances to get an answer here, please make your question self-contained, see How to ask
